# Django internal 200 error after changing some code

Tags: django

I have a git repository, which I use for my django project. When I change something locally, then I push it and pull it at my "real" server. My settings.py files are ignored, so that there is no conflict. After the latest pull however, I get the following error:

```
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] No handlers could be found for logger "django.request"
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=30560): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/src/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 236, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/views/debug.py", line 91, in technical_500_response
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/views/debug.py", line 350, in get_traceback_html
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return t.render(c)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 148, in render
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self._render(context)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 142, in _render
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/template/debug.py", line 80, in render_node
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return node.render(context)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/template/debug.py", line 90, in render
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 624, in resolve
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 769, in date
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return format(value, arg)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 343, in format
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return df.format(format_string)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 268, in r
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/encoding.py", line 85, in force_text
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     s = six.text_type(s)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/functional.py", line 144, in __text_cast
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 83, in ugettext
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 325, in ugettext
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 306, in do_translate
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 209, in translation
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/libraring/webapps/libraring/lib/python2.7/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 189, in _fetch
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
[Sun Jul 05 16:59:05 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

Also, when I open my url I get an 'internal 200 error'.

Interestingly, when I run the django app on the server as it would be ran locally, ie. 'python manage.py runserver' I get no error whatsoever.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "200 error". 200 is a success code. Maybe you are getting a 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset --hard <OKcommitSHA>` to restore your files to a previous state. `OKcommitSHA` is the actual commit key when everything was fine.

More details about [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

You could also use `git diff HEAD <OKcommitSHA>` to see whats changes were applied since the last pull and therefore see where is the issue located.